# how to disable all the touch except for the tooltip to show

Tags: highcharts

How is it possible to disable all the touch from the chart i.e I dont want to enable the scroll of the data over time as this causes errors in data collection if lets say u switch between 1 year and 6 months. for example if 1 year is chosen, I only want to show data for one year with enabling the scroll, while having the tooltip to work

```
rangeSelector:{
            buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                fill: 'none',
                stroke: 'none',
                'stroke-width': 0,
                r: 8,
                style: {
                    color: '#000',
                    'text-decoration':'underline',
                    'font-weight':'bold',
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        fill: 'none',

                    },
                    select: {
                        fill: '#fff',
                        style: {
                            color: 'black',
                            'text-decoration':'none',
                            'font-weight':'node',
                        }
                    }
                    // disabled: { ... }
                }
            },
            selected: 0,
            inputEnabled: false,
            buttonSpacing : 10,
        },
```

Comment: i.e what I want is to enable the tooltip but to disable and movement across the graph

Comment: So you want to disable panning? http://jsfiddle.net/m554b72h/